# Managed equivalent of DestroyIcon

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a managed or multiplatform equivalent of DestroyIcon (one that is portable)?
My current code is:

```
Icon newIcon = Icon.FromHandle(bitmap.GetHicon());
Program.main.Icon = newIcon;
newIcon.Dispose();
```

However, Dispose() isn't enough, and the icon's memory is leaked. Because this is run many times, the program quickly runs out of memory and crashes. The documentation says to use `DestroyIcon(newIcon.Handle);`, but this requires

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
extern static bool DestroyIcon(IntPtr handle);
```

and user32.dll isn't available on anything besides Window. My application needs to run on Windows, Mac, and Linux. I did some research, and the Mono website says,

> If you are calling something that is provided by your platform
>   (usually the win32 API), you will have to find a way to accomplish the
>   same functionality on all your target platforms. This could mean
>   replacing your unmanaged call with a managed equivalent, or it can
>   mean detecting what platform you are running on and calling the
>   Win32/*nix/OSX/etc. equivalent.

[pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/DestroyIcon.html) says that Omnicoder's Managed Windows API is an alternative, but it does not provide the DestroyIcon method.

Comment: There is no managed equivalent that I am aware of. `Icon.Dispose` wouldn't release the handle to the icon because it was created by the `Bitmap`, not the `Icon`; it isn't the Icon's job to manage that handle.

Comment: Note the [//FIXME comment](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/cc6aa17cbe21deef23588ce63ab2b365b6cda651/src/System.Drawing.Common/src/System/Drawing/Icon.Unix.cs#L140).  Until that's fixed you don't have to worry about it.  Ought to take a while.